# How to perform face recognition over millions of faces in a second

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

We can see the modern applications having the face recognition feature, performs the recognition in seconds from databases contain millions of faces.
I am wondering how they do that with triplet loss that effieciently.

What are databases they use?

How do they query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We feed two face images to a CNN to represent them as vectors. This is face verification. Face recognition requires to apply face verification many times.

Suppose that you will compare target.jpg with img1 to img5.

```
target.jpg - img1.jpg
target.jpg - img2.jpg
target.jpg - img3.jpg
target.jpg - img4.jpg
target.jpg - img5.jpg
```

Here, img1 to img5 are already stored in my db. I can feed them to a CNN model to represent before. I mean that when I got target.jpg, I already have to representation for img1 to img5.

In real time, you need to find the representation of target.jpg in real time. Comparing vectors can be handled very fast.

You can test it with the following code block.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream("C:/database")
```